# jQuery validation, how to auto clear error messages of hidden fields?

Tags: jquery-validate

The jquery validate plugin auto removes error messages of visible fields when a value is entered, i have one hidden field populated by custom events whose error messages do not auto clear when the value is set. What would be a clean way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1):

OK, should anyone be interested in how to do this here is a simple way:

```
$('.error:contains("here goes the text of the error message you want to remove")').remove();
```